# Concatenate two digit year with number formatted with leading zeros

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, number-formatting, leading-zero

I am trying to create an invoice number with VBA in excel. I want the invoice number to be displayed "YY####" where the number is formatted with leading zeros and will increase by one with every new invoice.

Here's what I have tried:

```
Sub Invoice()
Dim inv As Long
inv = Range("e5")
Range("e5") = Format(Now(), "yy") & inv + 1
End Sub
```

And that returns YY#.

I'm not sure how to fit the number format in the code so that it includes leading zeros.

Comment: Have you tried using `Format$(inv + 1, "0000")`? Btw, [ask] specifically says not to use screenshots of code, so please [edit] your question with the code *as text*.

Comment: I think there's an error in your logic. As YY is already included in your inv, and then you append YY again inv = 1 beomes 241, then 24242, 2424243...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this code:

```
Sub Invoice()
    Dim inv As Long
    inv = Right(Range("e5").Value, 4)
    Range("e5").Value = Format(Date, "yy") & Format(inv + 1, "0000")
End Sub
```

Start from any number.